# Как определить код страны в номере?

Tags: android

Нашел решение, брать код страны и соответственно нему подставлять +7, +380 и т.д.

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String code = telephonyManager.getSimCountryIso();
```

Но оно работает не на всех телефонах. На самсунге s8 возвращает null. Есть какой-то ещё способ определить код страны без gps?

Comment: Код какой страны?

Comment: Код страны по номеру телефона

Comment: Это понятно. Какой страны-то? Откуда звонят, куда я сам звоню, где зарегистрирован телефон, где находится телефон? Что-то ещё?

Comment: По сим карте, установленной в телефон

Answer (score 2):

Данный способ действительно иногда может работать не так как нужно, на различных устройствах и зависит от уровня API девайса, от типа сим-карты,  и её наличия в устройстве.

Можете попробовать данную библиотеку.
https://github.com/google/libphonenumber

Она позволяет определять страну по первым введенным цифрам номера телефона.

Как подключить её и как пользоваться подробно описано тут:
https://medium.com/@youngam/android-how-to-detect-a-country-code-by-the-phone-number-30bacd606bbc

Либо можно написать свою реализацию, запихнув к примеру в хешмапу все 252 страны и соответствующие им номера.